# How to define assemblies in rd.xml for .Net Native (corert)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, native

I wrote some .Net Core and using Dapper library and using corert build to .Net Native

But Its have some error and I found solution solve by rd.xml

I try to define many value but its can’t use

And I want to know how to listing and define runtime directive?

This my code https://github.com/ifew/corert-db-dapper?files=1